# How to add shadow to DrawerLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]
[image]

I have this thing up and running but I want to add this shadow in the view. I tried shadow via XML , tried wrapping inside `CardView` didn't work. Any help will be appreciated. If you want I will post more code.

**Main activity XML file**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:openDrawer="start">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/nav_host"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

            <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
                android:id='@+id/navigationView'
                android:layout_width='@dimen/nav_drawer_width'
                android:layout_height='match_parent'
                android:layout_gravity='start'
                android:scrollbars="none"
                app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_drawer_selector_background"
                app:itemIconSize="30dp"
                app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_drawer_icon"
                app:itemTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_drawer_text"
                app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu"
                tools:headerLayout="@layout/layout_header" />

        </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_log_out" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This function is called inside `onDrawerSlide` function in `DrawerLayout.DrawerListener`

```
private fun animateMainView(drawerView: View, slideOffset: Float) {

        val scaleFactor = 6f

        val slideX = drawerView.width * slideOffset
        fragment.view?.translationX = slideX
        fragment.view?.scaleX = 1 - (slideOffset / scaleFactor)
        fragment.view?.scaleY = 1 - (slideOffset / scaleFactor)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a View on it and set backGround color to it

and work with visible and invisible .

I hope this Help to you.

Comment: Any example you wanna post?

Comment: just set background color with low opacity for main layout and change it when menu opened or when u want.